# Same query fetching different results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am following this article series to learn about ROLLUP and CUBE

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10471/tsql-lab-6-using-with-cube-to-generate-subtotal-and-grand-total-rows.aspx

For this query:

```
select
    case
        when grouping(CustomerName) = 1 then 'All Customers' 
        else CustomerName
    end as CustomerName,
    case
        when grouping(ItemName) = 1 then 'All Items'
        else ItemName
    end as ItemName,
    sum(quantity*pricepercase) as Amount1
from orders
group by CustomerName, ItemName 
with cube
```

The author has result like this:

```
CustomerName         ItemName             Amount
-------------------- -------------------- ---------------------
Jacob                Item 1               312.50
Jacob                Item 2               480.00
Jacob                All Items            792.50
Mike                 Item 1               75.00
Mike                 Item 2               44.00
Mike                 All Items            119.00
All Customers        All Items            911.50
All Customers        Item 1               387.50
All Customers        Item 2               524.00
```

The two extra rows generated by cube are the last 2 rows. I get results like this:

```
CustomerName         ItemName             Amount
-------------------- -------------------- ---------------------
Jacob                Item 1               312.50
Mike                 Item 1               75.00
All Customers        Item 1               387.50
Jacob                Item 2               480.00
Mike                 Item 2               44.00
All Customers        Item 2               524.00
All Customers        All Items            911.50
Jacob                All Items            792.50
Mike                 All Items            119.00
```

The first result set looks appropriate. Why is there a difference when I run it?

Comment: Don't use `WITH CUBE` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx *Use the ISO compliant syntax for all new work. The non-ISO compliant syntax is provided for backward compatibility.*

Comment: Oh! That is good to know. `CUBE( elem1, elem2)` instead of `WITH CUBE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC SQL does not guarantee any order except when you explicitely have an `ORDER BY` in place... sometimes different SQL Server versions/patchlevels "order" differently without an `ORDER BY`.

I don't know whether the author produced that result using SQL Server 2005 or 2008 or 2008 R2 etc. BUT I higghly suspect that this is the reason for what you see...

IF you need a specific order in the resultset always use an explicit `ORDER BY`clause!

Comment: Ok, I suspected it could be that order is not guaranteed. However, if I do `rollup` instead of `cube`, I get the same order of results as the author. That is when I wondered if it could be something else. As you said, the author may have used a different version of SQL Server.

Comment: If it turns out to be a case of different versions, is there a feature in the version that produces results in different order?

Comment: @KishorNanda any DB vendor is free to change the internal algorithms any way they want as long as the result is standards-conforming - this makes it hard to tell what feature might be related to such change...